# Add static image to django

Tags: python, django

**Updated**  my folder structure is as below:
    After run manage.py collectstatic coomand, the django's static files are copied to my project folder as below, then i put my logo.png to its img/

```
 mysite_new/

      manage.py
      mysite/
      ------ __init__.py
             urls.py
             setting.py
             wsgi.py
             templates/
                      default.html
             static/
                     img/
                          logo.png
                          .....
      ticket/
      ------__init__.py
            models.py
            view.py
            urls.py
            ......
```

In setting.py, i set

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_URL = ''
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

and in mysite/urls.py i set

```
        urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/', hello),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT },name="media"),



)
```

## default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>staitc sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png"" alt="hahhaa">
</body>
</html>
```

In ticket/view.py

```
def hello(request):
     return render_to_response( 'admin/default.html')
```

Then in web browser, in input `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello`, it show [image]

Then i load the image from the “hahhaa", it link to 
[image]

No picture shown, so maybe the image path is incorrect and the image is not loaded successfull.
  Who can help me to make thie image picture show in my hello method of view.py ?
  This question confused me for a long time, thanks for your help in advance.
  My django version is 1.4.

I have already found the solution, no need to move my static folder, just keep it the same level with ticket/ , and then add ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/' in setting.py

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: No, i do not run that command.

Comment: I run `manage.py collectstatic` then the project copy the static files to my project folder mysite/. Then what should i do? Put the logo.png to mysite/static/admin/img/ ?

Comment: Wrong order.  You put your static files in the static folders, like mysite/static/admin or whatever, and _then_ you wrong `manage.py collectstatic`.

Answer (score 0):

You should move static directory to mysite. The url to logo will be 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/logo.png

And set STATIC_ROOT one level up:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'static')
```

This is where collectstatic command will copy static files of the project and apps.

UPD:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT },name="media"),
```

Here should be settings.STATIC_ROOT. For development you can also use:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-development

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

And at the bottom of the file

```
if settings.DEBUG and settings.MEDIA_ROOT:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your urls files. You take to django serve function path to media root not your static.

try it:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^hello/', hello),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT },name="media"),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png"" alt="hahaha">
```

Correct syntax-

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png" alt="hahhaa">
```

or

```
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt="hahhaa">
```